# Embedding django-postman templates

Tags: django, django-views

I have a page which displays 2 types of information: general (user name/full name of the current user for ex) and specific (a list of friends if the page is "Friends" ). 
When going to another url, the general information remains unchanged, while the specifics change ( a list of locations for the "Locations" page).

So far I implemented this using a views hierarchy: the base view is responsible for the general information, while the child view is responsible for the specifics.

In templates I use "extends": base template -> general information, specific template that extends the base template -> specific information.

All works well.

Now I decided to use django-postman, and I want to embed the postman template in the base template.

My question is: what is the best way to do this?

So far the only solution I could find was to use "extends" and add code that adds what I need into context to the django-postman views.  I do not like this solution at all.

Is there a more elegant way?